# Python Don't Repeat Consecutive Lines

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am writing a python script, that will show the status of a raspberry pi's gpio input pins in a web browser. This script is just for the backend testing:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
os.system('clear')

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(29, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(37)
    if input_state == False:
        print('One')
        time.sleep(0.2)
    input_state = GPIO.input(32)
    if input_state == False:
        print('Two')
        time.sleep(0.2)
    input_state = GPIO.input(29)
    if input_state == False:
        print('Three')
        time.sleep(.02)
```

My output crazily spams the screen with the number until the input switch is turned off. How can I prevent the same consecutive line from repeating immediately?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about printing only when the input states actually change? Something like this (untested):

```
# Your code to initialise everything:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
os.system('clear')

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(29, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# New loop keeping track of the previous ("old") input states:
old_input_states = [None] * 3
while True:
    input_states = [GPIO.input(n) for n in (37, 32, 29)]
    if input_states != old_input_states:
        for n, name in enumerate(['One', 'Two', 'Three']):
            if input_states[n] == False:
                print name
        old_input_states = input_states
```

So to explain what this new loop code is doing:

- First, a list `old_input_states` is created which contains three `None` entries. This will be used to remember the last state of the three GPIOs.
- Then at the beginning of the loop, the `GPIO.input(n)` function is called, for `n` being 37, 32 and 29 for the three GPIOs. The resulting list `input_states` now contains the three GPIO states.
- Then this list is compared against the `old_input_states` list and if they differ, it will do the following:

  - For each `name` in `'One'`, `'Two'` and `'Three'` (which are enumerated by `n`, i.e. for `'One'` it is 0, 1 for `'Two'` and 2 for `'Three'`), it checks the value of that `input_states[n]` to see if it is `False` and if it is, it prints the `name` which should match the corresponding GPIO.
  - Then it updates `old_input_states` to match `input_states` so in the next loop, it will only check (and potentially print) again if the `input_states` changed.

**EDIT**

Note that the code will output **all** GPIOs which are currently `False` at the point where a change is detected. To only print the ones going from `True` to `False`, you should be able to use the following code for the section starting with the `# New loop` comment:

```
# New loop keeping track of the previous ("old") input states:
old_input_states = [None] * 3
while True:
    input_states = [GPIO.input(n) for n in (37, 32, 29)]
    for n, name in enumerate(['One', 'Two', 'Three']):
        if input_states[n] != old_input_states[n] and input_states[n] == False:
            print name
    old_input_states = input_states
```

**EDIT 2**

As indicated by the OP, the preferred output is in list-form anyway. Also there appeared to be some bouncing happening on the switch inputs to the GPIOs, which could be improved by using the `time.sleep` calls. Further, the output should be inverted. The final code of the `while` loop looks like this:

```
old_input_states = [None] * 3
while True:
    input_states = [GPIO.input(n) for n in (37, 32, 29)]
    if input_states != old_input_states:
        inverted_input_states = [1 - i for i in input_states]
        print inverted_input_states
        time.sleep(0.2)
    old_input_states = input_states
```

*Disclaimer: For better debouncing reliability of switches I'd use different code, but that is beyond the scope of this question*

Comment: How/where would I implement this? I am pretty new to python.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth sorry for being unclear, this should replace your `while True` loop. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, so when I turn on 2 or 3 (not one), and turn it off within like 3 seconds then it show the `Two` when I turn it off also.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth the code will, on each change, print **all** GPIO states that are currently `False`. If that is not what you want and rather see only the changed GPIO, you need a slightly modified version. I tried to add an explanation how the code is supposed to operate. To help you understand it better, you can also add a `print input_states` line just above the `for n, name` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89208/discussion-between-skyler-spaeth-and-friendfx).

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your code to work with an 'on change' type logic:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
os.system('clear')

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# allows you to rename the io ports
io_names = [ 'One', 'Two', 'Three' ]

class IOMonitor():
    def __init__( self, num , io, pud ):
        self.num = num

        GPIO.setup(self.num, io, pull_up_down=pud)
        self.last_state = GPIO.input(self.num)

    def poll( self ):
        # detect current state
        current_state = GPIO.input(self.num)
        # compare with old state
        if( current_state != self.last_state ):
            # set new last state
            self.last_state = current_state 
            # print name of io that changed
            print( io_names[self.num] )


ioMonitors = [
    IOMonitor(29, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP),
    IOMonitor(32, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP),
    IOMonitor(37, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
    ]


def main():
    while True:
        for io in ioMonitors:
            io.poll()
            time.sleep(0.2)

main()
```

I don't have access to your libraries so this code is untested but should be logically correct.

Comment: I get a syntax error on the line containing IOMonitor(32,…) but not the others. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the commas! There you go.

Comment: Ok so now whenever I execute it, it just runs with no output for 1 second, then goes back to the terminal window.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth mmm you may not be running this in the main module then. I'll delete the `if` statement, which should allow it to run.